# Hot water spigot in bathroom shuts off aftere a few seconds

Tags: water-pressure

When i run the hot water in my bathroom sink, after a few seconds i hear a bang behind the wall and the hot water shuts off.  This only happens at this one location.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I wonder if the washer in your hot faucet might be loose. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: It sounds like a thermostatic anti scald valve is malfunctioning and abruptly turning the hot off to prevent scalding.